# Control audio volume using physical controls on the phone in webapp

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am using opentok.js in my webapp.

When I open a page with tokbox video stream, I cannot control audio volume using physical audio buttons. Instead they change the ring volume.

When I add  tag to the page and I play it, I am able to use physical audio buttons to change volume of that  file but not the tokbox video stream.

Perhaps as a workaround it's possible to direct tokbox audio stream to  tag? It doesn't seem to be attached to the element that gets created before videoElementCreated event is fired. Because when I don't add this event.element to the DOM, I still hear the sound. Where it is coming from if it's not in the DOM?